# Where are the latest drivers for the Intel HD Graphics 4000?

Tags: macos, driver

Strangely enough, I haven't been able to find any official website or webpage that hosts the official Intel HD Graphics 4000 latest drivers for OS X (10.9, to be specific).

Where are the drivers hiding?

Comment: HD4000... Intel? Camera? HD4000 what??? If you are looking for the Intel drivers, what do you need them for? Is your system experiencing any issues?

Comment: The graphics "card/chip/processor". I simply figure that it's good practice to make the latest drivers widely available. I was having problems with VirtualBox and 3D acceleration, but I think I've managed to isolate that problem to VirtualBox's application logic rather than anything actually being broken on my system.

Comment: I'd still like to know where those drivers are, though, just for reference.

Comment: The video drivers for Mac OS X are packaged with the OS and not available separately, AFAIK.

Comment: Drivers on Mac are kernel extensions and can be found in `/System/Library/Extensions` directory. There's for example: `AppleIntelHD4000Graphics.kext`

Comment: Fascinating. I was worried that this might be the case. This puts a frowny face on my day. XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drivers for Intel GPU HD4000 are modified by apple and the revisions are delivered to you bundled in software updates.

If you want a access to specific driver open the installation package from 10.9 with specific tools for that and get it from there.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a little bit on that and listing a couple examples of the "specific tools" for said job?

Comment: I can do that, but please ask as new question, something like How to extract os x installer package contents. I assume we are done with this one then.